# Unable to access struct variable defined inside #if directive

Tags: ios, swift, struct, environment, preprocessor-directive

I've successfully configured 3 different environment in my project. I'm trying to acceess base URL based on configurations set in scheme.

How can I access variable named 'BASE_URL' from below code like

> AppConstants.API.BASE_URL

```
class AppConstants
{
    struct API
    {
        #if ENV_DEV
        static let BASE_URL = "http://api_dev .../"
        #endif

        #if ENV_STAGE
        static let BASE_URL = "http://api_stag .../"
        #endif

        #if ENV_PROD
        static let BASE_URL = "https://api_prod .../"
        #endif
    }
}
```

I know this can be done as I'm able to access like this way in other project :

**UPDATE :**

- From other project :

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2 :**

I've set environment vars in active comilation conditions as :

[image]

I think I'm missing something, may be in build setting.

Comment: Why does this need to be a class?

Comment: How to you access it, and what is the error message?

Comment: Does it even compile? Your `BASE_URL` declarations from compiler point of view are not mutually exclusive. Nothing (except developer's attention) protects from two or all three `#if` checks to pass and `BASE_URL` being declared multiple times.

Comment: @user28434: It *does* compile if exactly one of ENV_DEV/ENV_STAGE/ENV_PROD are defined  as "other Swift flag" in the build settings.

Comment: Guys, please have a look at my edit. I can access the var in same way. I believe I'm missing something minor.

Comment: Where/how do you define ENV_* in the build settings?

Comment: @MartinR I've added ENV_* in active compilation conditions

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the relevant build settings?

Comment: @MartinR please have a look at Update 2 for definition of environment vars.

Comment: @iAkki: There is a typo: ENV_STAG in the build settings and ENV_STAGE in the code. Apart from that, it should work exactly as you did it.

Comment: Ooops ! such a silly mistake. Thanks to point me out @MartinR. Now its working.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic (simple typographical error).

Answer (score 2):

Just tested the following code and it should work. You basically need to convert it from all `#if`'s to using `#elseif` and `#else`. This is because there could be a chance that `BASE_URL` won't exist if none of the statements are true.

You could also set a default value and change it in each of your `if` statements. But somehow you need to define what the variable will be if none of the `if` statements are true.

```
class AppConstants
{
    struct API
    {
        #if ENV_DEV
        static let BASE_URL = "http://api_dev .../"
        #elseif ENV_STAGE
        static let BASE_URL = "http://api_stag .../"
        #else
        static let BASE_URL = "https://api_prod .../"
        #endif
    }
}

print(AppConstants.API.BASE_URL)
```

Keep in mind this solution will default to the last base url if the if statements aren’t true. In the original question there was no default. It depends on your configuration if this behavior is acceptable or not.

Comment: Thanks. This works perrfect. But why it won't be accessible with onlt #if, like one shown in screenshot in updated question ?

Comment: I’m not sure why your first update screenshot worked. I think you should be safe and set default values. As user28434 said nothing protects against it being declared multiple times except developers attention. Which is normally a bad thing and opens the door to problems. Code defensively. Using if else statements here with default values and ensuring that BASE_URL will always be declared seems like the best way to go.

Comment: I disagree with this solution. If every configuration requires a dedicated base URL, then a missing definition in the build settings is a *programming error* and should not compile, instead of silently falling back so *some* URL. – Also it does not explain why OP's code does not compile.

Comment: @MartinR If you have a better solution feel free to post it. Although I agree with what you are saying I couldn’t access that variable without ensuring it’s declared. Not sure how you can do that using the original code. But feel free to answer if you have a better solution. Pros and cons to everything.

Comment: I do not have an answer because I cannot reproduce OP's problem. Perhaps it is only the typo in the build settings (see my above comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828305/unable-to-access-struct-variable-defined-inside-if-directive?noredirect=1#comment82621094_47828305)

Comment: @MartinR Fair enough. But yes I agree that there are downsides to my solution. It will always use that default if there is a problem. In some cases that’s maybe what you want. In other cases you do want that to fail. Depends on your config and how you want to handle it.

Comment: @MartinR Just updated my answer to more clearly reflect this discussion. Hopefully that helps. Thanks for your input.

Comment: MartinR and Charlie, Thanks for your collaboration. Finally, after correcting misspelled ENV_STAGE to ENV_STAG suggested by Martin I'm able to access variable as in screenshot. Now, I just want to know which one is better to go for ?

Comment: @iAkki It depends on what you want. If there is a problem in your code like a misspelling like you had. Do you want it to use a default base url (my solution above)? Or do you want it to throw an error (your code after correcting misspelling)? Either way technically works. But it depends on what you want and how you want to handle those programmers mistakes and edge cases.

Comment: this is not compiled

Comment: @JeetendraKumar What? That makes no sense.

Comment: @CharlieFish I removed constants from other swift flags then compiled but everytime else case is executing. ENV_DEV is not accessible

Comment: @JeetendraKumar Well obviously that is going to create problems. If you try to access that variable and it doesn’t exist it’ll fail. What’s your question?

Comment: @CharlieFish How to access ENV_DEV and ENV_STAGE case

Comment: @JeetendraKumar That sounds like a completely separate question. Feel free to post on Stack Overflow. But this question was very specific and I believe I answered it. If you have a new question feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @CharlieFish Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To protect yourself from not setting proper compile flag you may use something like that:

```
class AppConstants
{
    struct API
    {
        static let BASE_URL: URL = { () -> URL in // URL should be URL
            let baseURLString: String

            #if ENV_DEV
                baseURLString = "http://api_dev .../"
            #endif

            #if ENV_STAGE
                baseURLString = "http://api_stag .../"
            #endif

            #if ENV_PROD
                baseURLString = "https://api_prod .../"
            #endif

            return URL(string: baseURLString)! // If no proper flag is set, you will get error here
        }()
    }
}
```

Here, if don't set any of flags, you will get error.

And it keeps raising error if you set more than one flag like your original code.